# Getting Event Source Pointer from Ada Event Handler Parameters

Tags: gtk, ada

With GtkAda, I want to identify which radio button was toggled.

The best I have come up with is this not very pretty code, which iterates over all of the buttons to find which ones toggled:

```
   procedure On_Pgm_Btn_Click
      (Button : access Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record'Class) is

     Button_Array : array (Positive range <>) of Gtk_Radio_Button := (Pgm_Bit, Pgm_1, Pgm_2, Pgm_3, Pgm_4);

   begin
     for Index In Button_Array'range loop
        if Button_Array(Index).Get_Active then
           Selected_Program_Button := Button_Array(Index);
           exit; 
        end if;
     end loop;
  end On_Pgm_Btn_Click;
```

This is called with this handler connection code:

```
   Gtkada.Handlers.Widget_Callback.Connect (Pgm_Bit, "toggled", On_Pgm_Btn_Click'Unrestricted_Access);   
   Gtkada.Handlers.Widget_Callback.Connect (Pgm_1, "toggled", On_Pgm_Btn_Click'Unrestricted_Access);   
   Gtkada.Handlers.Widget_Callback.Connect (Pgm_2, "toggled", On_Pgm_Btn_Click'Unrestricted_Access);   
   Gtkada.Handlers.Widget_Callback.Connect (Pgm_3, "toggled", On_Pgm_Btn_Click'Unrestricted_Access);   
   Gtkada.Handlers.Widget_Callback.Connect (Pgm_4, "toggled", On_Pgm_Btn_Click'Unrestricted_Access);
```

I can see in the debugger that the value of the parameter *Button* has the same address as the button that generated the event, but I don't know the conventional way that this parameter is used. It's type is Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record'Class, which suggests to me that I might be hacking the code if I did an unchecked conversion to a radio button;

How to I get the Radio Button from the parameter Button?

(Also, if there is a better way to get the state of a radio button group, I would like to know. I haven't been able to find any good examples.)

UPDATE with Solution
From the accepted answer below, I understand that a view conversion is implemented simply like a function call, as shown in the examples of [ARM 4.6](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-6.html#p5). The handler became this:

```
procedure On_Pgm_Btn_Click
  (Button : access Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record'Class) is

  This_Button : Gtk_Radio_Button;

begin
  This_Button := Gtk_Radio_Button(Button);
  if This_Button.Get_Active then
     Selected_Program_Button := This_Button;
  end if;
end On_Pgm_Btn_Click;
```

The types involved are already defined in gtk-radio-button.ads as:

```
   type Gtk_Radio_Button_Record is new Gtk_Check_Button_Record with null record;
   type Gtk_Radio_Button is access all Gtk_Radio_Button_Record'Class;
```

and in gtk_widget.ads as:

```
   type Gtk_Widget_Record is new GObject_Record with null record;
   type Gtk_Widget is access all Gtk_Widget_Record'Class;
```

so there was no reason to redefine them or use the packages and sample code provided in the accepted answer.

The important line in the modified code is:

```
This_Button := Gtk_Radio_Button(Button);
```

which performs the view conversion.

Comment: To be pedantic, a view conversion (like any type conversion) _looks_ like a function call; probably not _implemented_ like one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be handled by a view conversion ([ARM 4.6(5)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-6.html#p5)), not an unchecked conversion.

I don’t have Gtk installed, so I wrote this (after some research at [AdaCore’s documentation](http://docs.adacore.com/gtkada-docs/gtkada_rm/gtkada_rm/docs/gtk.radio_button.html#L106C9)), which is I believe a self-contained equivalent, and which compiled successfully with GCC 5.1.0.

```
package View_Conversions is

   type Widget_Record is tagged null record;
   --  Represents Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record

   type Button_Record is new Widget_Record with null record;
   type Button is access all Button_Record'Class;
   --  Represents Gtk.Radio_Button.Gtk_Radio_Button

   procedure On_Click (Widget : access Widget_Record'Class);

end View_Conversions;
```

with body

```
package body View_Conversions is

   Selected : Button;
   --  Records the selected button

   procedure On_Click (Widget : access Widget_Record'Class) is
   begin

      Selected := Button (Widget);
      --  If the Widget is a Button, save it; if not, raise CE

   end On_Click;

end View_Conversions;
```

The advantage over unchecked conversion is that this is a checked conversion, and if the passed `Widget` isn’t in fact a `Button` you’ll get a `Constraint_Error` at the point of the conversion.

Comment: This is unfamiliar to me. Where does the Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record come into the picture? It's Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record'Class that's passed to the handler. This compiles by itself, but I can't refer to it from the call to connect (no candidate interpretations match). I assume this is because the signatures don't match.

Comment: Apologies if I’ve misunderstood your question -- My code is a simplified version that (I hope) demonstrates a possible solution. I declared `Widget_Record` to correspond to `Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record` because I don’t (need to) have access to the real thing. The body of my `On_Click` should readily translate to your environment; `Selected_Program_Button := Gtk_Radio_Button (Button);`

Comment: Ok. This wasn't as complicated as I thought. I'll post my solution, based on your help, in my question. Thanks.